# Run external command via Laravel Artisan Console

Tags: laravel, console, laravel-artisan

I'm looking to execute [psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) from Laravel to execute some remote command and I'd like to use the Artisan Console to do so (for now). Ideally, I'd like to navigate to a url and the command would be issued (something i'd implement after this initial stage).

What I have so far is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class RestartSplunk extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'splunk:restart {host}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Restart Splunk instance on given host';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $host = $this->argument('host');

        $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar();

        if ($this->confirm('Are you sure you\'d like to restart ' . $host )) {
            $this->info('Restarting ' . $host . '...');
        }
    }
}
```

If someone has implemented this or can share some resources to accomplish this it'd me much appreciated.

Comment: Can you not run it as a normal command using `exec` or `shell_exec`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer [The Process Component in Symphony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html).